# How to design db schema for complex mongodb searching

Tags: mongodb, search, unicode, full-text-search

Currently my document (schema) looks like this.

```
var Schema = {
    name: "fish",
    location: "United States, Michigan, Ann Arbor",
    description: {
        en: "newspaper",
        de: "zeitung",
        ch: "報紙"
    }
}
```

and I setup a text index as follows:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Optimally when user search for "newspapers" is working even when it's not exactly the same.

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "newspapers"}})  // ( ͡◉ ͜ʖ ͡◉)
```

But when the phrases are in unicode characters or non-English the search does not return the above document.

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "zeitungen"}})  // no result
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "大報紙"}})      // no result
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "news"}})      // no result
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is this solvable in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look on the ful text search by mongodb. It may help you, ya it is not replacement of Elastic serach , solr but it can solve your problem. [Reference]:(https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Comment: hmm. ya seems with mongodb you can only search plurals in English unless maybe you create the index by German at the beginning..